# How to extend a styled component to another component using props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm a benninger learning React with Styled Components.

*App.js*

```
const BasicButton = styled.button`
  background-color: purple;
`;
```

*Increase.js*

```
const StyledButtonIncrease = styled(props.BasicButton)`
  padding: 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
`;
```

How can I receive a Styled Component in another React component to extend the styling? I tried to use the example above but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will actually do is export the styled that you want to extend and import it in the file that you will create your new styled.

ex:

*App.js*

```js
export const BasicButton = styled.button`
  background-color: purple;
`;
```

*increase.js*

```js
import { BasicButton } from '../App.js';

const StyledButtonIncrease = styled(BasicButton)`
  padding: 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
`;
```